# Why first homology group of torus is isomorphic (as abelian group) to lattice?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $T＝\Bbb C/Λ$ be a torus($Λ$ is lattice).
I heard first homology group $H_1(\Bbb C/Λ,\Bbb Z)$ is isom as abelian group to $Λ$ via the map
$r→\oint\mathrm dz$ (we integrate across the cycle $r$).

Could you tell me the proof of the fact that 'this map is well-defined and surjective and injective'?
(I could only understand this map is group hom )

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Canonical map between lattice and first homology group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189441/canonical-map-between-lattice-and-first-homology-group)

Comment: Your link is asking completely another thing from this question. Indeed, Ofcourse related, but not duplicate.

Comment: I can't say explicitly too much about the map you have in mind, but I can give you a good reason why this happens abstractly. First, for a path connected space $X$, there is an isomorphism $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \pi_1(X,x_0)^{\text{Ab}}$ where the second group is the Abelianization of the fundamental group at $x_0 \in X$. Using that $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = T^2$ as topological spaces and $\pi_1(T^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ gives you an isomorphism $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cong  \Lambda.$

Comment: It is important that this isom is given by canonical integral map. The isom itself is just saying both Z-module is rank 2(too weak statement) and obvious from general topology ( just saying torus is generated by two cycles).

Comment: This is just the obvious fact that $\int_{0}^{\lambda} dz= \lambda$ for every $\lambda\in {\mathbb C}$.

Comment: The integral  is not on C, but on C/Λ.

Comment: @Neronoggshafareivh: Right, and this is how you compute integrals in ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda$, by lifting the path to the complex plane.

Comment: Then, should I pull back differential $dz$ on C/Λ by $π:C→C/Λ$? Could you tell me how to calculate this? And the result(well defined ness) follows from integral by substitution?

Comment: $dz$ is already the pull-back, you are abusing the notation pretending that it's a form on the elliptic curve. I will write details in a day or so, when I have more time.

Comment: In other word, why $∮r     dz＝∮π^-1(r)    dz$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some generalities. Suppose that $X, Y$ are Riemann surfaces and $f: X\to Y$ is a holomorphic covering map, $\alpha, \beta$ are holomorphic 1-forms on $X, Y$ respectively such that $f^*\beta=\alpha$. Suppose that $b$ is a piecewise-smooth loop in $Y$, more precisely, $b: [0,1]\to Y$ such that $b(0)=b(1)=y$. Fix a point $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $f$ is a covering map, there is a unique path $a: [0,1]\to X$ such that $a(0)=x$ and $f\circ a=b$. Then
$$
\int_a \alpha = \int_b \beta. 
$$
(this is just the formula of change of variables in integrals once you unravel what's written).

Now, suppose that $X={\mathbb C}$, $\Lambda$ is a lattice in  ${\mathbb C}$; I'll regard $\Lambda$ as a group of biholomorphic transformations acting on ${\mathbb C}$ properly discontinuously and freely, so $Y={\mathbb C}/\Lambda$ is a nonsingular complex elliptic curve and the quotient map $f: X\to Y$ is a holomorphic (universal) covering map. The holomorphic 1-form $\alpha=dz$ is invariant under $\Lambda$, hence, it descends to a holomorphic 1-form $\beta$ on $Y$ such that $f^*\beta=\alpha$. I'll fix the base-point $x=0\in X={\mathbb C}$ and let $y=f(x)\in Y$. Take a loop $b$ in $Y$ based at $y$, i.e. $b(0)=b(1)=y$. As noted above, the loop $b$ lifts to a unique path $a: [0,1]\to {\mathbb C}$ such that $a(0)=0$; hence, $a(1)=\lambda\in \Lambda$. We have
$$
\int_b \beta= \int_a \alpha = \int_0^\lambda dz= \lambda
$$
(since $X$ is simply-connected, the integral is independent of a path connecting $0$ and $\lambda$). If loops $b_1, b_2$ in $Y$ are homotopic, then $\int_{b_1}\beta= \int_{b_2}\beta$ (since the form $\beta$ is closed). Thus, we get a well-defined map
$$
\phi: \pi_1(Y,y)\to \Lambda, [b]\mapsto \int_b \beta.  
$$
Since the correspondence between the relative homotopy classes $[b]\in \pi_1(Y,y)$ and the group of covering transformations
$\Lambda$ given by $[b]\mapsto a(1)$ is a group isomorphism, we see that the map $\phi$ is an isomorphism as well. Lastly, the group $\pi_1(Y)$ is abelian, so is naturally isomorphic to $H_1(Y)$.