# Canonical map between lattice and first homology group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let T＝C/Λ be a lattice.
I heard first homology group $H1(C/Λ,Z)$ is isom as abelian group to Λ via the map
$r→∮ dz$(we integrate across the cycle $r$).

Is this canonical map?

Comment: "Canonical" means "not depending on auxiliary choices", thus the map which assigns to a $1$-cycle $\gamma$ (not a line, what is a line on the torus?) the value $\int_\gamma\,dz$ is certainly canonical.

Comment: Thank you very much.